# Exoplayer: Failed to get vendor from drm plugin: -19

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3, android-drm

Why the error occurs?

Sometimes in logs I see this while playing songs:

```
DrmHalHidl       E  Failed to get vendor from drm plugin: -19
DrmHalHidl       E  Failed to get description from drm plugin: -19
```

What is code `-19` about?

Versions:

```
androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.1
androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.1.1
```